# Looking for an adjective meaning "perfect in a way that looks effortless, but isn't"

Tags: single-word-requests

There was a particular word which describes a **"quality(or level of perfection?) which looks very smooth and simple but requires a serious effort to achieve"**. That word was pictorially described by a meme where a whole iceberg was shown but most part of it submerged inside the water-body and only the tip which was visible for a person standing on the ground. It was signifying that the tip is appreciated by all but only a few know what's beneath the water-body(the greater part of the iceberg which is the metaphor used to describe the effort). Also let me know the etymological breakdown of the word.

> The way that gymnast moved was so _________, they made it look
>   effortless though I could never do it.

Comment: do you have an image for this meme?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=glacier+in+water&biw=1242&bih=617&tbm=isch&imgil=90aPL3d225fViM%253A%253B04R6fvAc9qmuTM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.fulcrumgallery.com%25252FGlacier-Dark-Blue-Water_682317.htm&source=iu&pf=m&fir=90aPL3d225fViM%253A%252C04R6fvAc9qmuTM%252C_&usg=__krJNOTAmV8woHuEWTGPv_D6UqqE%3D&ved=0CCYQyjdqFQoTCOPG9LL7qMcCFQoKjgodUkUBeQ&ei=UhPOVePVPIqUuATSioXIBw#tbm=isch&q=glacier+underwater&imgrc=sqNZi4dlWfU0uM%3A

Comment: I have an answer and it could be a good one. Could you give a sample sentence that uses the adjective but with a blank where it would fit? That extra context would allow us to see if our answers match what you are looking for. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, i just can't remember the word and it's usage at all. For example, you can use it to describe the gymnast, maybe, where his/her exercises seems pretty simple but in actuality requires years of practicing and body-flexibility. It is only when you try to do it yourself, you realize it. I am not sure but I think the word started with an 'S'.

Comment: Yes, single word requests should include at least one usage example. Please see the checklist at the bottom of the [tag wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) -- **write a sentence** including a blank for where your word should appear, perhaps using the gymnast example.

Comment: @JonyAgarwal - Well the gymnast scenario could be helpful. We just need you to turn it an *example* rather than an *explanation*.

Comment: okay, so here it goes: "The gymnastic performance was pretty _____. "

Comment: The meme I think of is a swan gliding gracefully on the surface and paddling frantically beneath (e.g. [this picture](http://www.themusicjungle.co.uk/live/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/swan-copy2.png)) called by some *The Swan Effect*. Lots of synonyms of [excellent](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/excellent) and [superb](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/superb) are known to mean that because most of us understand the masters make it look easy but I can't think of a single word that is defined as that.

Comment: that is definitely much much closer to the word I want. It is pretty uncommon. I forgot to mark it the first and unfortunately the last time I saw it.

Comment: Certainly "they made it look easy" is a fairly common idiom.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ideas:

**unlabored**

**artless, artlessly**

**uncontrived**

Or maybe

*The gymnast executed even the most difficult moves with **a simple elegance**.*

Answer (score 2):

I do believe the word you were looking for is Sprezzatura. It's a noun, however.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprezzatura)

> ***Sprezzatura*** [sprettsaˈtuːra] is an Italian word originating from Baldassare Castiglione's *The Book of the Courtier*, where it is defined by the author as "a certain nonchalance, so as to conceal all art and make whatever one does or says appear to be without effort and almost without any thought about it". It is the ability of the courtier to display "an easy facility in accomplishing difficult actions which hides the conscious effort that went into them". Sprezzatura has also been described "as a form of defensive irony: the ability to disguise what one really desires, feels, thinks, and means or intends behind a mask of apparent reticence and nonchalance".
>
> The word has entered the English language; the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sprezzatura) defines it as "studied carelessness".

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking at **casual virtuosity**

Casual supports the idea of easyness, while [virtuosity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/virtuosity) means great technical skills.

Comment: I like virtuosity, and I think it would work well, at least in the world of music, without "casual."  The only problem with it there would be that one might get the idea that the person tends to play flashy pieces (like Paganini).

Answer (score 0):

Deceptively? ie the hard work put in to achieving that level makes the activity of the gymnast appear easy when it is actually very hard.

Comment: Please modify this so the example actually uses deceptively and is an example.

Comment: I suppose you are proposing *So-and-So's gymnastics routine appeared deceptively simple*.

Comment: Yes, sorry. When I posted 'deceptively' the example sentence had not been posted. I was suggesting So-and-So's gymnastics......etc.

Comment: @MaryP - In a case like this, it's a good idea to edit your answer.  You'll see, there's a gray link that says "edit" just below your answer, between "share" and "flag."  Just click on that.